# Why is eating chazir (pig) a "worse" issur than eating a nevelah (animal that wasn't shechted properly)?

Tags: food, meat, eating

Rashi writes in Chulin Daf 106a that

> בשר חזיר חמור מנבלה דאית ביה תרי איסורי
>
> (Eating) pig meat is worse than (eating meat of) a nevelah (an animal that wasn't slaughtered properly), since there are two prohibitions (when it comes to eating the pig meat, whereas eating nevelah is only one prohibition).

What two prohibitions are there? Why is this worse?

Comment: Don't eat non kosher animals. Don't eat pig. Those are separate pesukim.

Comment: Its a machlokes Rashi and the Rambam ses it in this tshuva. http://www.mail-archive.com/daf-discuss@shemayisrael.com/msg00149/chul-106.1c1.pdf